# Connect to a single WCF service with two different endpoint bindings

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I am new to WCF and (I hope) I'm having a "noob" problem.  I searched the site and did not find the answer I'm looking for.  I apologize if this has already been answered and I missed it.

I am programmaticly connecting to my service using a **ChannelFactory**.  The problem I'm having is that the client cannot connect to my first service endpoint, unless I comment out the second one (the MSMQ one).  Hopefully that helps.

The contracts are different, and I'm specifying the correct bindings (WSDualHttpBinding and NetMsmqBinding, respectively) on the client-side.

Please let me know if there is a way to fix this, or if more information is required.

I appreciate the help.

Tyler

```
<services>          
   <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior" name="[intentionally removed]"> 
       <endpoint 
           address="[intentionally removed]" 
           behaviorConfiguration="DefaultEndpointBehavior"
           binding="wsDualHttpBinding" 
           bindingConfiguration="DualBinding"
           name="WrapperEndpoint"
           contract="[intentionally removed]" 
       />
       <endpoint 
           address="[intentionally removed]"
           behaviorConfiguration="DefaultEndpointBehavior"
           binding="netMsmqBinding"
           bindingConfiguration="MsmqBinding"
           name="MsmqEndpoint"      
           contract="[intentionally removed]"
       />
    </service>
</services>
```

Comment: Are the endpoint addresses different?  Also, can you post a code snippet showing how you're using ChannelFactory?

Comment: You stated that "The contracts are different" but I would expect them to be the same, and it looks like in your code you use `IContract` for both. Are the contracts for the 2 endpoints the same interface, or different?  I believe typically WCF would want them to be the same.

Comment: Is there an error that your client gives when it can not connect? Also, you may want to enable tracing on your WCF service and see if you get anything meaningful out of the log: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751526.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This topic might be related: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/wcf/thread/643371b4-00a7-472b-8bea-3055f2eb90ed

I don't think you can have a single service with 2 different contracts. I think when you have both endpoints, WCF is just failing to start up properly, but when you comment out 1 endpoint, then it works fine because all endpoints share the same contract.

WCF is also going to try to define a WSDL for the service (not per endpoint) based off the contract, but if the service has more than 1 contract, it won't know what to do.

The proper thing to do would be to split this into 2 services.

---

*Edit:*

On the other hand, [this article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dhananjaycoder/1345/) indicates that having a service with multiple endpoints with different contracts works just fine, so perhaps I am wrong.

Hmmm....